# iptables port forward - get source ip and port

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I have an Router with LEDE. There, I have a default Portforwarding set up in a NAT environment. When the destination gets an request, the Source IP has been rewritten with the IP of the Router and the Source-Port has been rewritten to a random Port of the Router. It would be awesome to retain the source IP and Port. Sadly this seems not possible when I have to use NAT.

Now, I search for a way to get the original Source IP and Port based on the Masqueraded Port opened on the router. This theoretically has to be possible because it's the information that is backwritten in the answer-packet. Is there a command how to look that up? Or would I have to rewrite iptables? I look for something like this:

```
$ iptables -t nat --lookup-masquerading-table --masqueraded-port 98765
Original Source-IP:      192.0.2.146
Original Source-Port:    7890
Original Dest-IP:        198.51.100.123
Original Dest-Port:      1234

Masqueraded Source-IP:   10.0.0.1
Masqueraded Source-Port: 98765
Masqueraded Dest-IP:     10.0.0.2
Masqueraded Dest-Port:   1234
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what exactly you want to know. What exactly is "Dynamic Port opened on the router"?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks for pointing that out! I have updated the question. Hopefully, it's more readable now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can see the masquerade NAT entries in `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` or `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`. The file has one line for each connection tracked by IPTables. Each line shows the address / port information for both incoming and outgoing packets for a particular connection.

If the incoming IP address is different from outgoing IP address, then it is a NAT connection and one can parse the information you need from it.

There is also the tool `netstat-nat`, which handles the process above and simply shows the NAT connections going through the device. One can also further filter the connections via command line options.